# NewListItemForm with pre-defined values from selected Entry inside form

Tags: lookup-column, list-form

i got two lists. One is called 'Projects' the other one 'Reports'. When i insert a new report i got the following fields

```
Associated Project: <LOOKUP FROM PROJECTS_TITLE>
Current StartDate: <I WANT TO GRAB THIS VALUE FROM PROJECTS_STARTDATE DEPENDING ON SELECTED LOOKUP>
Current EndDate: <I WANT TO GRAB THIS VALUE FROM PROJECTS_ENDDATE DEPENDING ON SELECTED LOOKUP>
New StartDate: <DATEPICKER>
New EndDate: <DATEPICKER>
```

This should be something pretty trivial, but i am really lacking google skills to find out about how to manage this. I sort of had this running doing via InfoPath, but this is not wanted.

If there is a programmatically way (or SP-Only-Way) those are to be preferred.

With what keywords can i find about what i want to do with StartDate and EndDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so trivial.
Take a look at [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) and see if it fits.

And take a look at this QA:

[Pull values from a lookup column using SPServices()](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22493/pull-values-from-a-lookup-column-using-spservices)

Comment: Okay well, the JavaScript way was alerady in my head, luckily there is a pre-coded library at hand, so thank you for that link. I still feel like i wanna cry though :S