# Invalid Look up Value . A look up field contains invalid data

Tags: lookup-column

I have a multi select Lookup column . I have to populate values to the lookup column from another column on a button click. I achieved it using below code but when i try to click ok/save it is throwing error "Invalid Lookup Value" . Please help.

Note : I am doing this only through javascript /javascript client object model

```
var possible = document.createElement("OPTION");
possible.text = fieldValue[i];
possible.value = i;
possible.selected=true;
tagTarget.options.add(possible);
GipAddSelectedItems(fieldObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the look up field is bound to a correct List/field.

I suggest you check and try to add some values manually and see if it works and after try and work out the programmatical approach.

The second thing, you cannot add into look up field just string, it has to be a look up value. So it is not just a string, but a different type of object or it should be an ID of the item. [check this out](http://sarangasl.blogspot.be/2009/12/add-item-to-list-with-lookup-column.html)

Just investigate it, as the error says it all, that what you add is not correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error says it all, the value which you are adding doesn't come from a lookUp field.
If lookup field is binded to some list, within the values like: green, yellow and red.
But you try to add 'black' you will get this kind of error.

Or another problem might be that the lookup field isn't binded to a correct source.

I also recommend to check this out:
[Pull values from a lookup column using SPServices()](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22493/pull-values-from-a-lookup-column-using-spservices)

Comment: Yeah... Actually the Value i am trying to add is single line of text retrieved from different list ...